# Troubleshooting CORS Issues with OpenAI API on a Website Served Over Ngrok

Tags: javascript, express, cors, openai-api, ngrok

I am currently facing a persistent Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issue that is preventing users from successfully using the OpenAI API on my website. My setup involves a website served over a secure HTTPS connection (https://www.bookgenerator.xyz), which interacts with a backend server exposed to the internet through Ngrok, substituting the localhost environment. This backend server is designed to handle requests to the OpenAI API.

However, the functionality works flawlessly only when accessed from my Mac's Chrome browser; it fails across all other devices and browsers, including Safari on Mac and Chrome on different machines. Users attempting to use the OpenAI API through the website encounter a "preflight response not successful" error, which indicates that the CORS preflight checks are failing.

Here are the specific details and steps I have taken:

1. Frontend Setup: The frontend is a simple HTML page that collects user input and sends it to the backend via JavaScript's Fetch API. The requests are directed to the Ngrok URL of my local server.
2. Backend Setup: My backend is an Express.js application running on Node.js. It uses the `cors` middleware to handle CORS issues. The server is designed to relay the requests it receives to the OpenAI API and return the responses back to the frontend.
3. Ngrok Configuration: I use Ngrok to create a tunnel to my localhost, which provides me with a public HTTPS URL. I have verified that the Ngrok tunnel is functional and correctly configured to forward requests to my local server.
4. CORS Middleware: In my Express.js setup, I have the CORS middleware in place. I have tried both the simple `app.use(cors());` setup and more detailed configurations specifying the origin, methods, and headers. Despite this, the preflight requests seem to be unsuccessful.
5. Successful Local Testing: When testing locally on my Mac using Chrome, the application works without any CORS issues. The requests to the OpenAI API are successful, and the expected functionality is achieved.
6. Failure on Other Devices/Browsers: When accessing the website from other devices and browsers, the preflight request fails, indicating that the CORS headers are not being recognized or are missing from the response.
7. Error Messages: The console error indicates that the preflight request has been blocked due to the lack of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the preflight response. Additionally, a `net::ERR_FAILED` message is observed, which could suggest network-related problems or issues with the Ngrok service itself.

I am looking for assistance in resolving these CORS issues so that all users can interact with the OpenAI API through my website, regardless of their device or browser. The solution needs to ensure that the CORS preflight checks are passed and that the API can be accessed as intended in a secure and reliable manner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AI Book Writer</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="aibookgenerator.ico">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-gray-100 font-sans leading-normal tracking-normal">
    <main class="container mx-auto max-w-4xl p-8 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl mt-6"> <!-- Adjusted max-width here -->
        <h1 class="text-4xl text-center text-gray-800 font-bold mb-6">AI Book Writer</h1>
        <p class="text-center text-gray-600 mb-10">Download PDF Upon Completion</p>
        <div class="space-y-4">
            <div class="number-inputs-form flex items-center">
                <label for="chapter-input" class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mr-2">Number of Chapters: </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-input w-1/7 border-2 border-black rounded-md" id="chapter-input" min="1" max="1">
            </div>
            <div class="number-inputs-form flex items-center">
                <label for="subchapter-input" class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mr-2">Number of Subchapters per Chapter: </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-input w-1/7 border-2 border-black rounded-md" id="subchapter-input" min="1" max="3">
            </div>
            <div class="number-inputs-form flex items-center">
                <label for="paragraph-input" class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mr-2">Number of Paragraphs per Subchapter: </label>
                <input type="number" class="form-input w-1/7 border-2 border-black rounded-md" id="paragraph-input" min="1" max="7">
            </div>
            
            <form id="topic-form" class="mt-8">
                <input type="text" id="topic-input" placeholder="Enter A Topic (Examples: Concord Jet, Quantum Computing)" class="form-input mt-1 block w-full border-2 border-black rounded-md py-3">
                <button type="submit" class="mt-4 w-full bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-blue-700">Generate Book</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="loading-message" class="hidden text-center mt-4"></div>
    
        <!-- New upgrade button (initially hidden) -->
        <button id="upgrade-button" class="hidden mt-4 w-full bg-red-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded hover:bg-red-700" onclick="https://www.bookgeneratorupgrade.xyz';">
            Get Free Trial for Unlimited Full Book Generation
        </button>

        <div id="book-content" class="mt-4"></div>
    </main>
<script>
    let tocEntries = []; 

    document.getElementById('topic-form').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const topic = document.getElementById('topic-input').value;
        let var_i = parseInt(document.getElementById('chapter-input').value);
        let var_j = parseInt(document.getElementById('subchapter-input').value);
        let var_k = parseInt(document.getElementById('paragraph-input').value);

        // Set default values if inputs are empty or invalid
        var_i = (!var_i || var_i < 1 || var_i > 5) ? 1 : var_i;
        var_j = (!var_j || var_j < 1 || var_j > 4) ? 3 : var_j;
        var_k = (!var_k || var_k < 1 || var_k > 8) ? 7 : var_k;

        document.getElementById('book-content').innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content
        showLoadingMessage(); // Start the loading message
        await generateBookContent(topic, var_i, var_j, var_k); // Pass the user-defined values to the function
        clearInterval(loadingInterval); // Stop the loading message
        document.getElementById('loading-message').style.display = 'none'; // Hide loading message
        document.getElementById('upgrade-button').style.display = 'block';  // Display the upgrade button
    });






    const generateBookContent = async (topic, var_i, var_j, var_k) => {
        let lastChapterTitle = ""; // Initialize variable for the last chapter title.
        let lastSubchapterTitle = ""; // Initialize variable for the last subchapter title.
        let tocEntries = []; 

        for (let i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            const chapterPrompt = `Generate a unique chapter title for the topic: ${topic}, distinct from the last title: ${lastChapterTitle}, and keep title less than 4 words. Also don't include double quotes around title.`;
            const chapterTitleMessage = [{ role: 'user', content: chapterPrompt }];
            const chapterTitleRaw = await sendToBackend(chapterTitleMessage); // Send only the current message
            const extractedChapterTitle = extractGeneratedText(chapterTitleRaw, chapterPrompt);
            const chapterTitle = extractedChapterTitle.startsWith('Chapter') ? extractedChapterTitle : `Chapter ${i}: ${extractedChapterTitle}`;
            displayChapter(chapterTitle);
            lastChapterTitle = chapterTitle; // Update the last chapter title

            for (let j = 1; j <= var_j; j++) {
                const subchapterPrompt = `Generate a unique subchapter title for ${chapterTitle} and keep title less than 6 words. Book is about ${topic}. Do not include ${i}:${j} so example, do not include anything like "1.2 Growing" and do not include any double quotes in this subchapter title` ;
                const subchapterTitleMessage = [{ role: 'user', content: subchapterPrompt }];
                const subchapterTitleRaw = await sendToBackend(subchapterTitleMessage); // Send only the current message
                const extractedSubchapterTitle = extractGeneratedText(subchapterTitleRaw, subchapterPrompt);
                const subchapterTitle = `${extractedSubchapterTitle.startsWith('Subchapter') ? extractedSubchapterTitle : `${extractedSubchapterTitle}`}`;
                displaySubchapter(subchapterTitle);
                lastSubchapterTitle = subchapterTitle; // Update the last subchapter title
                tocEntries.push({ title: subchapterTitle, type: 'subchapter', chapter: i, subchapter: j });


                let previousParagraph = '';

                for (let k = 1; k <= var_k; k++) {
                    let paragraphPrompt;
                    if (i === 1 && j === 1 && k === 1) {
                        // Specific prompt when both j and k are 1
                        paragraphPrompt = `Write a single, concise paragraph for the opening text of this book about ${topic} starting in subchapter about ${subchapterTitle}, Include Real historical examples or interesting true story examples if relevant."`;
                    } else {
                        // General prompt for other cases
                        paragraphPrompt = `Write a single, concise paragraph (number ${k}) for ${subchapterTitle}, following the previous content without repeating or introducing new subtopics. Include Real historical examples or interesting true story examples if relevant. The book is about ${topic}. Focus on continuing the discussion seamlessly: "${previousParagraph}"`;
                    }
                    const paragraphMessages = [{ role: 'user', content: paragraphPrompt }];
                    const paragraphHistory = paragraphMessages.concat({ role: 'system', content: previousParagraph }); // Only remember the previous paragraph
                    const paragraphResponse = await sendToBackend(paragraphHistory);
                    const paragraph = extractGeneratedText(paragraphResponse, paragraphPrompt); // Function to extract the generated text
                    if (paragraph) {
                        // displayParagraph(paragraph);
                        displayParagraph(`${paragraph}`);
                        previousParagraph = paragraph; // Set the last paragraph for the next iteration
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case where paragraph content is not generated properly
                        console.error('Failed to generate paragraph content.');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        const subscriptionNote = "\n\n\nTo access the remaining chapters, please upgrade.";
        displayParagraph(subscriptionNote, 'bold-red-text'); // Display the final note with bold red styling

    };

    let loadingInterval; // Declare this outside so you can clear it later

    function showLoadingMessage() {
        const loadingElement = document.getElementById('loading-message');
        loadingElement.style.display = 'block';
        loadingElement.style.color = '#00D100'; // Make the text color green
        let dotCount = 0;
        loadingElement.innerText = 'Generating Book';

        loadingInterval = setInterval(() => {
            dotCount = (dotCount + 1) % 4; // Reset after 3 dots
            loadingElement.innerText = 'Generating Book' + '.'.repeat(dotCount);
        }, 500); // Update every 500 milliseconds
    }


    function extractGeneratedText(response, prompt) {
        // Check if the response contains the prompt text
        if (response.includes(prompt)) {
            // Extract and return the text after the prompt
            return response.split(prompt)[1].trim();
        } else {
            // The response does not contain the prompt, return the whole response or handle accordingly
            return response;
        }
    }

    const sendToBackend = async (messages) => {
        const response = await fetch('https://c258-50-218-62-78.ngrok-free.app/chat', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ messages })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.completion;
    };

    

    const displayChapter = (title) => {
        const element = document.createElement('h2');
        element.innerText = title;
        element.className = 'text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800 mt-6 mb-4'; // Larger and bolder text
        document.getElementById('book-content').appendChild(element);
    };


    const displaySubchapter = (title) => {
        const element = document.createElement('h3');
        element.innerText = title;
        element.className = 'text-xl font-semibold text-gray-700 mt-4 mb-2'; // Prominent but smaller than chapter titles
        document.getElementById('book-content').appendChild(element);
    };


    const displayParagraph = (text, className = '') => {
        const paragraphElement = document.createElement('p');
        paragraphElement.innerText = text;
        if (className) {
            paragraphElement.className = className; // Add the class if provided
        }
        document.getElementById('book-content').appendChild(paragraphElement);

        const breakElement = document.createElement('br'); // Create a new line break element
        document.getElementById('book-content').appendChild(breakElement); // Append the line break for extra spacing
    };

    // ... (rest of your code, no changes until the download button event listener) ...
    document.getElementById('upgrade-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Handle the click event, e.g., redirect to the upgrade page or show a message
        window.location.href = 'https://www.bookgeneratorupgrade.xyz'; // Redirect to the exact upgrade page (change the URL as needed)
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my index.js backend.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import openaiPackage from 'openai';

const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = openaiPackage;
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "XXXXXX",
    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXX", // censored for privacy 
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Use cors middleware to handle CORS requests
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/chat", async (req, res) => {
    const { messages } = req.body;
    
    try {
        const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({ 
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: messages
        });
        res.json({completion: completion.data.choices[0].message.content});
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error processing the OpenAI API request:", error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Error processing your request" });
    }
});

app.get('/home.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'home.html'));
});

// Handle root URL ("/")
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'home.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```